# Capture update event via Laravel observer

Tags: php, laravel, events, laravel-8, observers

I'm trying to trigger some action after create and update my model following Laravel docs regarding events and observers. So I have:

\App\Observers\PedidoObserver.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Observers;

use App\Pedido;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
class PedidoObserver {
    public $afterCommit = true;

    public function created(Pedido $pedido)
    {
        Log::info('A new order has been created and the properly method has been triggered');
    }
    public function updated(Pedido $pedido)
    {
        Log::info('An order has been updated and the properly method has been triggered');
    }
}
```

Boot function in \App\Providers\EventServiceProvider.php:

```
public function boot(){
    parent::boot();
    Pedido::observe(PedidoObserver::class);
}
```

Created method succeeds when a new order is created from one of my controllers with this code:

```
//...
Pedido::create($pedido['header'])->save();
```

however, even though my order is successfully updated from another controller method, the updated event never gets executed:

```
//...
Pedido::where([['numserie', $numserie], ['estado', 'SC']])->update(['estado'=> 'P', 'estadonombre' => 'Pendiente de pago'])
```

Answer (score 2):

It’s because model events dont fired in [batch update models](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#events).

You must update EXACTLY model, not with where query.

You need to change your logic for use observers for something like this:

```
Pedido::where([['numserie', $numserie], ['estado', 'SC']])->firstOrFail()->update(['estado'=> 'P', 'estadonombre' => 'Pendiente de pago'])
```

Comment: Ok, I understand it. But I don't need firstOrFail because is a massive update.

Comment: Than, you cannot use Model Events in your case.

Comment: Btw, you can get your models with query and foreach them with update - events will be fired. But it's not the right solution :)